# Delete image from folder

Tags: php

I am trying to delete images when the user click on delete

```
if (isset($_GET['sid'])) {
    $sid = $_GET['sid'];
}


$getImageName = "SELECT * FROM header_image_arabic WHERE id='" . $sid . "'";
$QgetImageName = $db->query($getImageName) or die($db->error);
if ($Fname = $QgetImageName->fetch_object())
    $myImageName = $Fname->image;
// delete image from dir function
$dir = "../images/backSlider_arabic/";
opendir($dir);
if (dir($dir)) {
    $filename = $myImageName;
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink("../images/backSlider_arabic/" . $filename);
        echo 'File' . $filename . 'has been deleted';
    } else {
        echo 'Could not delete ' . $filename . ',file does not exist';
        echo "<br />" . dirname("../images/backSlider_arabic/") . ".<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "Dir not there";
}
closedir();
```

every time I click on delete it come with "Could not delete myfile.jpg, file does not exist'"

**Edit mySql with more security**

```
if(isset($_GET['sid'])){
     $sid=$_GET['sid'];
}
    $getName = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM header_image_arabic WHERE id=?");
    $getName->bind_param('s', $sid);
    $getName->execute();
    $result = $getName->get_result();
    if($Fname=$result->fetch_object())
    $myImageName=$Fname->image;
    //delete image from dir function
    $dir="../images/backSlider_arabic/";
    opendir($dir);
    if(dir($dir)){
    $filename=$myImageName;
    if(file_exists("../images/backSlider_arabic/".$filename)) {
    unlink("../images/backSlider_arabic/".$filename);
    echo'File'.$filename.'has been deleted';
    }else{
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.',file does not exist';
    echo "<br />".dirname("../images/backSlider_arabic/").".<br />";
    }
    }else{echo"Dir not there";}
    closedir();
```

I have updated my code since the mySql query was very poor on security I used  **Prepared statements** to better way.

Comment: Very bad approach! Anyone can end up deleting all your files.

Comment: What is the question? It told you what is wrong, the given path is invalid.

Comment: How can I do it with better way?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection; you should read on [how to prevent them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: @gpgekko but I am sure the path is right

Comment: @moonwave99 You said that don't rely on `$_GET` in order to perform `DELETE` what should I rely on to get the `id` then, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you really need to properly check and escape your variables! Your script is really bad thought about.

However, if it is for learning, regarding your question, an error is problably in:

```
if(file_exists($filename)) {
```

which should be

```
if (file_exists("../images/backSlider_arabic/".$filename)) {
```

But please, adjust and fix your script, you are leaving it open for anyone like this, to delete whatever they like.

Comment: i thought of that too ... but then i saw `opendir($dir);` do you need the full path when navigating into the folder before?

Comment: I dont think so, but this serves more as an educational answer. I was trying to say that he should check for and delete same file. In his script he is checking one file, and deleting another. 

Meaning, if he trully does not need the path in file_exists() then the unlink() file path is wrong. Or vice versa, if he needs the path the file_exists() is wrong.

That's why I want to point out that he should check for and delete the same file.

Comment: @kasipovic: you are totally right about that

Answer (score 0):

i hope you check for more things than `isset($_GET['sid'])`

for debugging purpose use echo or var_dump to show the path/image before you try to delete it

and check your server if you have the right rights (read/write)

Comment: Also the other if (!isset()) makes no sense because he continues execution afterwards